# tocloft \cftpartpresnum not working with titlesec

Tags: errors, titlesec, tocloft

I have come across a strange issue: I want to change the `\part` number in my TOC the same way that I have done it for `\chapter`:

[image]

The way I achieved that for the chapter heading is with this command:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\color{myred}}
```

I also use `titlesec` to change the appearance of my `\part` and `\chapter` headings. When I now try to use

```
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\color{myred}}
```

to change the `\part` number, nothing happens and I get the above output. I am not given any error. I have put together a MWE, where I was able to reproduce the issue. It seems strange to me that `titlesec` and `tocloft` are not compatible.

I have found a work-around which though produces the caveat that now the pdf bookmark carries the 'colour code' I used. which obviously is not ideal. So rather than now trying to fix this by trying to overwrite the bookmark name, I am interested to solve this issue between `tocloft` and `titlesec`.

```
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\color{myred}\Roman{part}\color{black}}
```

[image]

I am going to include the MWE and the code I used to modify my `\part` using `titlesec`:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
   \definecolor{myred}{RGB}{239, 0, 0}
   \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,200}
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpages}{xcolor}

\usepackage{tocloft}
        \renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\color{myred}}

        \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\color{myblue}}

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
    \part{Trial name of Part}
    this is a blind text

    \chapter{Trial chapter}
    this is more blind text

    \section{Trial section}
\end{document}
```

modifying code:

```
    \usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\Huge\fontsize{30pt}{60pt}\filcenter}{\partname{} \color{myred}\thepart}{0em}
\makeatother
```

Comment: `titlesec` and `tocloft` should not be used together.

Comment: ok, I see that, but why is this error occurring altogether? I have essentially fully customised the TOC using `tocloft` and except for this one incompatibility with the `\cftpartpresnum` command, everything else worked when using it in parallel with `titlesec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `titlesec`, I  suggest you load its companion package `titletoc` in the place of `tocloft`:

```
  \documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

\usepackage[newparttoc] {titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\Huge\fontsize{30pt}{60pt}\filcenter}{\partname{} \color{myred}\thepart}{0em}
\makeatother
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, pdfpages]{xcolor}
   \definecolor{myred}{RGB}{239, 0, 0}
   \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,200}
\titlecontents{part}[1.5em]{\large\bfseries}
{\contentslabel[\color{myred} \thecontentslabel]{1.1em}}
{}
{\hfill\contentspage}

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
    \part{Trial name of Part}
    this is a blind text

    \chapter{Trial chapter}
    this is more blind text

    \section{Trial section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I was missing the `[newparttoc]` option in `titlesec` to get it to render the `\part` number correctly, when using `titletoc`. I am still curious about `tocloft` and `titlesec` not working together properly though, if you have some more insight

Comment: Yes, the documentation explains that `\part` is managed in a special way by LaTeX, and this has implications for `titletoc`.

Comment: actually there is a last problem remaining: the alignment of the page number of `\part` is not in line with the other page numbers. Is there a way of adjusting the `\hfill` command?

Comment: Actually, I don't have this problem, but I've found out that the part number is in the left margin. I'll fix it in a moment,  hoping you won't have this alignment problem of the page number. Else, please post a short code showing the problem.